# How to get the caret index in a WPF DataGrid cell?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

TextBoxes have the CaretIndex property to know in which position you are adding characters. I've been using that to restrict which characters you can type in a TextBox (double with scientific notation for instance disallow decimal separator right of E, +/- can only be placed in first position or immediately after a E, etc.).

I'd like a way to do the same, except in a DataGrid cell. The column is restricted to double, but that doesn't prevent users from typing things that aren't a double (or cannot become a double).

So how do I know in which position I am adding characters in a DataGrid cell? FYI, I'm using framework 4.0

Comment: I can always check after the edit (and I will, even if it's just to be safe), but what I was looking for was a way to check while editing. FYI, paste and deletion aren't handled for now, as it isn't an immediate requirement.

Comment: You could create a DataGridTemplateColumn and have a textbox inside the DataTemplate. This will give you access to all properties a regular textbox has